# How we can detect faces more accurately

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing face detection from video. So I wrote one small code to detect the face.

```
#include<opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<cv.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

CvCapture *capture=cvCaptureFromFile("foot.mp4");
double min_face_size=30;
double max_face_size=400;

Mat detectFace(Mat src);

int main( )
{
  namedWindow( "window1", 1 );  
  while(1)
  {
    Mat frame,frame1;
    frame1=cvQueryFrame(capture);;
    frame=detectFace(frame1);
    imshow( "window1", frame );
    if(waitKey(1) == 'c') break; 
  }

  waitKey(0);                 
  return 0;
}

Mat detectFace(Mat image)
{
  CascadeClassifier face_cascade( "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml" );
  CvPoint ul,lr;
  std::vector<Rect> faces;
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale( image, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,   Size(min_face_size, min_face_size),Size(max_face_size, max_face_size) );
 for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
  {
  min_face_size = faces[i].width*0.8;
  max_face_size = faces[i].width*1.2;
  ul.x=faces[i].x;
  ul.y=faces[i].y;
  lr.x=faces[i].x + faces[i].width;
  lr.y=faces[i].y + faces[i].height;
  rectangle(image,ul,lr,CV_RGB(1,255,0),3,8,0);
}
return image;
}
```

I took one video for face detection which contains both small and large faces. My problem is using my code, it detects only small faces and also it shows some unwanted detection.

I need to detect both small and large faces in a video. How shall I do this? 
Is there any problem with the scaling factor?

Please help me understand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to increase 'double max_face_size', which controls how large faces you want to detect.
2. You can also increase '2' in the parameters of 'detectMultiScale()', which controls the quality of the faces.

Comment: I increase the value of ' max_face_size'. But at that time it detect only large images.I want to detect both small and large images.